# Deleleting an entity object which was saved to context not happening in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using entityframework 6. I added an object to context and I am not saving the context. Now If I want to delete the object its not happening. How can I achive this. I want to save the changes finaly on save fuction. I did the sanme in Entity framework 4.0 before It was happening then. but I am unable to do it in Entity Fraamework 6.0.

Comment: Deleting from the database always required to invoke `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Please add the relevant lines of code so we can see what you are doing